# How does one expand a `fix` function just one step?

Tags: recursion, coq

I have defined a recursive function with `fix`, and now I want to prove a rewriting equation about it.
The function in question is a bit big, but here is another function that has the same problem.
(Here is an interactive collacoq with it: https://x80.org/collacoq/aweboxoxuy.coq)

```
Require Import Wf_nat PeanoNat.

Definition test (n: nat): nat. 
refine (
  let test := 
    fix test n (H: Acc lt n) {struct H} := 
      if Nat.eq_dec 0 n 
      then n 
      else n + test (n-1) _ 
  in 
    test n (Wf_nat.lt_wf n)).

  apply H; auto with arith.
Defined.

(* a unit test to see it works as intended. *)
Check eq_refl (test 4 = 4 + test 3).
```

I want to prove the following goal

```
Goal forall n, test (S n) = S n + test n.

Proof. 
   induction n. 
   reflexivity.
   unfold test.
```

but when I start working on it, I get a proof term with `fix test`
Now I just want to unfold this once, but `cbv delta` evaluates too much.

How can I reduce the `fix` function definition just once?

Here is the proof obligation

```
n: nat
IHn: test (S n) = test n + S n
1/1
(fix test (n0 : nat) (H : Acc lt n0) {struct H} : nat :=
   match Nat.eq_dec 0 n0 with
   | left _ => n0
   | right H0 =>
       n0 +
       test (n0 - 1)
         (match H with
          | Acc_intro _ H1 => H1
          end (n0 - 1)
            (Nat.sub_lt n0 1
               (Arith_prebase.gt_le_S_stt 0 n0
                  (Arith_prebase.neq_0_lt_stt n0 H0)) 
               (le_n 1)))
   end) (S (S n)) (lt_wf (S (S n))) =
(fix test (n0 : nat) (H : Acc lt n0) {struct H} : nat :=
   match Nat.eq_dec 0 n0 with
   | left _ => n0
   | right H0 =>
       n0 +
       test (n0 - 1)
         (match H with
          | Acc_intro _ H1 => H1
          end (n0 - 1)
            (Nat.sub_lt n0 1
               (Arith_prebase.gt_le_S_stt 0 n0
                  (Arith_prebase.neq_0_lt_stt n0 H0)) 
               (le_n 1)))
   end) (S n) (lt_wf (S n)) + S (S n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with function defined by well-foundness is always tricky. One reason is that you are often drown under big terms.
The main problem of your proof is (because of your induction) you are creating  `(S (S n))` so your function reduces too much by simplification!
As a matter of fact you don't need to prove your lemma by induction.
Let us try to convey some intuition. Your definition looks like.

```
test n = f n (lt_wf n)
```

so your function is defined by accessibility with the proof `(lt_wf n)`. What you actually need to prove is that `f` does not depend on the actual proof.

```
Lemma f_eq : forall n H1 H2, f n H1 = f n H2.
```

and you will be able to perform simplification.

Here is a proof of your Lemma

```
Goal forall n, test (S n) = S n + test n.
Proof.
intros n.
apply f_equal2 with (f := Nat.add); [trivial |].
set (f := ((fix test (k : _) (H : Acc lt k) {struct H} : _ := _))).
set (H := (_ : Acc _ (S n - 1))).
assert (f_eq : forall n H1 H2, f n H1 = f n H2).
- intros n1.
  induction n1.
  + intros H1 H2.
    dependent inversion H1; dependent inversion H2; simpl; auto.
  + intros H1 H2.
    dependent inversion H1; dependent inversion H2.
    apply f_equal2 with (f := Nat.add).
    * trivial.
    * destruct n1; apply IHn1.
- destruct n; apply f_eq.
Qed.
```